# Bitmap brush path on canvas - not a smooth path

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm trying to develop a game using a transparent canvas and a surfaceView,

1. I created a screen-sized off-screen bitmap (myCanvasBitmap).
2. Each time, I create a new Canvas for that Bitmap.
3. I draw on the Bitmap, with drawBitmap().
4. I copy the Bitmap to the Surface, with drawBitmap().

The problem is that if I draw "fast" (moving the finger fast),  the line isn't consistent-  the circle bitmaps are too far from each other.
But when I draw "slow", the circle Bitmaps are close.

Fast :
(OOOOO O__O______O_____________O_______________________         O)

Slow: (OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO)

I read some posts around here and realized I should use "drawPath" somehow (to be able to complete and draw all points between 2 positions,  but the problem is that "drawPath" works with paint which I don't have (I use a bitmap brush).

Does anyone know how I can add a path code to work with my kind of surfaceView program and solve this problem of breaking?

```
 public class SurfaceMyPaint extends SurfaceView implements Runnable 
  {
    Thread t;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Bitmap brush,myCanvasBitmap;
    boolean isItOk = false;

public SurfaceMyPaint(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    holder = getHolder();
    initial();
}

public void initial() 
{
    brush= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brush2);       
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {            
       x= event.getX();
       y= event.getY();
    }

   if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
   {
     x = event.getX();
     y= event.getY();
   }
   return true;
}


public void run()
{
    while (isItOk == true)
    {
    if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
        continue;
    myCanvas_w = getWidth();
    myCanvas_h = getHeight();
    if (myCanvasBitmap== null)
    {myCanvasBitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(myCanvas_w, myCanvas_h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);}
    Canvas c = new Canvas(myCanvasBitmap);
    canvas = holder.lockCanvas(null);
    c.drawBitmap(brush, x - (brush.getWidth() / 2), y - (brush.getWidth() / 2), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(myCanvasBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}}
```